# FluentAutomation instruct browser to navigate back

Tags: fluentautomation

I can't find a way press the browser back button or to inject a script that navigates back using FluentAutomation. Is there any way to do this at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is possible to inject a script to navigate back, like this:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)FluentTest.ProviderInstance).ExecuteScript(@"window.history.back()");
```